# Can you create a skill bonus item to give a bonus to Concentration?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

When a [concentration](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/magic.html#concentration) check is made **you roll d20 and add your caster level and the ability score modifier used to determine bonus spells of the same type.** (quoted)

If I was looking to create a [magical item](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/magicItems/magicItemCreation.html) to add a bonus to this, what should be used? This is not a skill check - as there is no skill involved - although to my mind would be the most obvious category for it if such an item could be created.

So is there a way to create a magical item that **would** give a bonus to this check?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, and there are several magic items that affect Concentration.  It's probably best to back-figure from those as the default magic item creation rules don't always give good results for unusual items.

Check out (on the better PFSRD):

- [Gloves of Elvenkind](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/e-g/gloves-of-elvenkind) - +5 to Spellcraft and Concentration checks while casting defensively, 7500 gp
- [Fortunate Charm](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/c-d/charm-fortunate) - reroll a skill or Concentration check 1/day, 3000 gp

The gloves of elvenkind are the best compare (in fact, you probably should just use them and move along). Cloak/boots are also +5 skill items for 2500.

Now the gloves do Spellcraft *and* Concentration, so you have to calculate that using the "two effects on one item" cost - like Gloves of Swimming and Climbing are 6250 gp, which is 2500 (Swim) + 2500 (climb) + 1250 (50%  of the second power combo cost).

Therefore the 7500 cost of these gloves is 3750 (Concentration) + 2500 (Spellcraft) + 1250 (50%  of the second power combo cost).  So Concentration bonuses could be said to be 50% more expensive than a skill bonus (bonus squared x 150 gp). Also, that bonus is only for casting defensively - I would assume that caveat would make a flat "bonus to Concentration checks in all circumstances" much more expensive. I have no basis for this than my opinion, but I'd go bonus squared x 500 gp - it's clearly intended to be less than a stat or save bonus, but more than a skill bonus.

In fact, there is also another more recent item that grants Concentration - [Tunic of Careful Casting](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/tunic-of-careful-casting). It adds a +2 flat bonus to all concentration checks and costs 5000 gp. That is slightly more expensive than my guess at (bonus squared * 625 gp), but that should be pretty authoritative since it's a direct compare. (Thanks to @Hettikus for that find.)

Comment: The usefulness of +2 to all concentration checks is greater than a bonus to cast defensively, which is only one the many uses for concentration checks. This difference can be noted aswell on feats that grant +2 to concentration vs combat casting with +4 to cast defensively.